# How can i get the all installed applciation names using iHasApp

Tags: iphone

iam developing one application.In that i am using the iHasApp third party application for getting the installed application names.But it gives only 4 application names(skype,Angry birds,Instagram,Talking Tom).So please tell me how to get the all installed application names using iHasApp or any other way to get the all installed application names.

Answer (score 1):

There is no 100% way to do this. I think iHasApp does it by checking for the app URL Scheme. But if an app does not have an URL scheme then detecting it will become all most impossible.

So you will have to accept that not all apps will be found, als you will only find app for which you know the app URL scheme.

Comment: How can i find out which app having URL Scheme?

Comment: Well you could grab the `info.plist` for each app you want to find. using software like [iExplorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/) to access to your iOS device file system.

Comment: In info.plist where we find the URL Scheme

Comment: Look for the `CFBundleURLTypes` which should contain `CFBundleURLSchemes` in this array you will find the URL scheme's

Comment: May i create that URL Scheme fro every app in device?

Comment: No, the developer of the app has to add the URL scheme, you can not create/edit `info.plist` of any app installed on your iOS device.